# Rename "Title" column on multiple lists

Tags: list, visual-studio, list-definition, xml

I have 3 or 4 lists where the title column is not required. Hence I started renaming the Title field to any other text field that I have in the list per the below blog.
http://spandothers.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/renaming-the-title-column-in-a-sharepoint-list/

When I started renaming the title column in the second list it threw an error while deploying, stating that a column with the same GUID already exists. So I changed the content type, `Inherits="FALSE"`.

Now everything works fine but I am not able to customize the "All Items" view in the list settings or create new views.
How can I get around it.

I am using VS2010, SP2010 and XML to create lists.

Answer (score 1):

If the title field is not needed it's better to not use it at all, than to use it for another text field. As standard it shows as a link and you have very little freedom with it (not to mention the other bugs it can throw up)

*If you want to exclude the Title field from your list and forms all you need to do is:*

1. Set the title field as not required under Columns
2. In Advanced settings set Content Types>Allow management of content types? to Yes
3. This will add a Content Types section to the settings. Click on Item under Content Type
4. In the list of columns click Title
5. Set Column Settings>This column is: to Hidden
   Save your changes and then set Allow management of content types? to No again
6. Exclude the title field from any views

It's a few more steps than just changing the name but it's far better for you site. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to change the Title column of a list programmatically.

```
var field = customersList.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title];
field.Title = "My New Title";
field.Update();
```

Check this answer:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/36024/11333